# Responsive menu not opening on IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

Why doesn't this `JS` code work in `IE11`? Burger menu does not open. Thought the problem was `onclick`, tried to do it via `addEventListener`, it still doesn't work.

//

I tried to use `Babel`, it didn't change anything, added only `"use strict"`.

//

`IE11` doesn't support `toggle`? [It says](https://www.caniuse.com/?search=classList.toggle) here that the second argument is not supported only.

//

Can you tell me how to get the code to work?

```js
document.querySelector(".animated-icon2").onclick = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  this.classList.toggle("open"); 
  document.querySelector(".sidebar-main").classList.toggle("show");
};
```

```css
.sidebar-main{
  display:none;
}
.sidebar-main.show{
  display: block;
}
.mobile-menu{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  top: 25px;
  right: 50%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 7;
}
/*animated icon*/
.animated-icon2 {
width: 30px;
height: 20px;
position: relative;
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
transition: .5s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;
}

.animated-icon2 span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
height: 3px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 9px;
opacity: 1;
left: 0;
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.animated-icon2 span {
background: #000;
}

.animated-icon2 span:nth-child(1) {
top: 0px;
}

.animated-icon2 span:nth-child(2), .animated-icon2 span:nth-child(3) {
top: 10px;
}

.animated-icon2 span:nth-child(4) {
top: 20px;
}

.animated-icon2.open span:nth-child(1) {
top: 11px;
width: 0%;
left: 50%;
}

.animated-icon2.open span:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.animated-icon2.open span:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.animated-icon2.open span:nth-child(4) {
top: 11px;
width: 0%;
left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <button class="mobile-menu"><div class="animated-icon2"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div></button>
    <div class="sidebar-main">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following JS code works for IE11.
The onclick event is executed for the button element in your HTML structure in IE11.

```js
document.querySelector(".mobile-menu").onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector(".animated-icon2").classList.toggle("open");
    document.querySelector(".sidebar-main").classList.toggle("show");
};
```

```css
.sidebar-main{
  display:none;
}
.sidebar-main.show{
  display: block;
}
.mobile-menu{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  top: 25px;
  right: 50%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 7;
}
/*animated icon*/
.animated-icon2 {
width: 30px;
height: 20px;
position: relative;
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
transition: .5s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;
}

.animated-icon2 span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
height: 3px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 9px;
opacity: 1;
left: 0;
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.animated-icon2 span {
background: #000;
}

.animated-icon2 span:nth-child(1) {
top: 0px;
}

.animated-icon2 span:nth-child(2), .animated-icon2 span:nth-child(3) {
top: 10px;
}

.animated-icon2 span:nth-child(4) {
top: 20px;
}

.animated-icon2.open span:nth-child(1) {
top: 11px;
width: 0%;
left: 50%;
}

.animated-icon2.open span:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.animated-icon2.open span:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.animated-icon2.open span:nth-child(4) {
top: 11px;
width: 0%;
left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <button class="mobile-menu"><div class="animated-icon2"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div></button>
    <div class="sidebar-main">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

Add this to the top of the HTML file.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Your page may be forced to an IE compatibility mode for some reason, which makes it behave like an old version of IE. Adding the meta tag forces it back into IE11 mode.